# Regex find greedy and lazy matches and all in-between

Tags: python, regex

I have a sequence like such `'01 02 09 02 09 02 03 05 09 08 09 '`, and I want to find a sequence that starts with `01` and ends with `09`, and in-between there can be one to nine double-digit, such as `02`, `03`, `04` etc. This is what I have tried so far.

I'm using `w{2}\s` (`w{2}` for matching the two digits, and `\s` for the whitespace). This can occur one to nine times, which leads to `(\w{2}\s){1,9}`. The whole regex becomes
`(01\s(\w{2}\s){1,9}09\s)`. This returns the following result:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 33), match='01 02 09 02 09 02 03 05 09 08 09 '>
```

If I use the lazy quantifier `?`, it returns the following result:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='01 02 09 '>
```

How can I obtain the results in-between too. The desired result would include all the following:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='01 02 09 '>
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 15), match='01 02 09 02 09 '>
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 27), match='01 02 09 02 09 02 03 05 09 '>
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 33), match='01 02 09 02 09 02 03 05 09 08 09 '>
```

Comment: Why not like `\b0[1-9](?: 0[1-9]){0,8}\b` https://regex101.com/r/wAYvnH/1

Comment: Maybe https://ideone.com/M0gnlX will do?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works, can you explain a bit about this strategy behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract these strings using

```py
import re
s = "01 02 09 02 09 02 03 05 09 08 09 "
m = re.search(r'01(?:\s\w{2})+\s09', s)
if m:
    print( [x[::-1] for x in re.findall(r'(?=\b(90.*?10$))', m.group()[::-1])] )
# => ['01 02 09 02 09 02 03 05 09 08 09', '01 02 09 02 09 02 03 05 09', '01 02 09 02 09', '01 02 09']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/M0gnlX).

With the `01(?:\s\w{2})+\s09` pattern and `re.search`, you can extract the substrings from `01` to the last `09` (with any space separated two word char chunks in between).

The second step - `[x[::-1] for x in re.findall(r'(?=\b(90.*?10$))', m.group()[::-1])]` - is to reverse the string and the pattern to get all overlapping matches from `09` to `01` and then reverse them to get final strings.

You may also reverse the final list if you add `[::-1]` at the end of the list comprehension: `print( [x[::-1] for x in re.findall(r'(?=\b(90.*?10$))', m.group()[::-1])][::-1] )`.

Comment: question: why would you use `\w{2}` instead of `\d{2}` or `0\d`, for example, wouldn't the first match `0X` or `XY` or something similar?

Comment: @David542 OP uses `\w{2}` in the original solution. Anyway, this is not that important here.

Comment: @David542 You are right, I could have used `\d` instead!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew @WiktorStribiżew May be a silly question, but can I also ask why it was necessary to reverse the list? Or is it possible to do it without reversing it? Just curious. 
Also, I didn't quite get the `m = re.search(r'01(?:\s\w{2})+\s09', s)` part, it seems that `m` is basically `s` again? It seems to work if I replace `m.group()[::-1]` with `s[::-1` as well.

Comment: @yvngpei When the input string is reversed, the match texts are reversed, too, so you need to reverse them back.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I got that part. I was just wondering why to have the input string reversed. Why it won't work if you don't inverse it, or why it was able to find all possible matches if you inverse the input?
A follow-up question, I want to limit the number of double-digits between 01 and 09, for example max occurs 3 times, I'm trying an expression like this `r'(?=\b(90[\s\d{1,4}]{1,10}\s?10))'`, `d{1,3}` because the digits can be more than 2, and `[\s\d{1,4}]{1,3}` because I like the double-digit to occur one to three times, but it doesn't work exactly as I thought.

Comment: @yvngpei Because you cannot match several times at the same position inside the string with regex. Since you end positions differ, reversing the string and matches will work, otherwise it won't. Use grouping constructs to quantify pattern groups: `re.search(r'01(?:\s\w{2}){0,3}\s09', s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This doesn't seem to include results such as `01 02 01 09`, it appears to find the results that starts with `01`, how can I adjust it so results that has `01` in between `01` and `09` also shows up? PS. results such as `01 09 17 09` do show up, which is great!

Comment: @yvngpei Then you should edit the question with this requirement and unaccept this answer. I doubt you need a regex here then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Alright, I will reconsider but for this task, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Here would be a non-regex answer that post-processes the matching elements:

```
s = '01 02 09 02 09 02 03 05 09 08 09 '.trim().split()
assert s[0] == '01'        \
   and s[-1] == '09'       \
   and (3 <= len(s) <= 11) \
   and len(s) == len([elem for elem in s if len(elem) == 2 and elem.isdigit() and elem[0] == '0'])
[s[:i+1] for i in sorted({s.index('09', i) for i in range(2,len(s))})]
# [
#    ['01', '02', '09'], 
#    ['01', '02', '09', '02', '09'], 
#    ['01', '02', '09', '02', '09', '02', '03', '05', '09'],
#    ['01', '02', '09', '02', '09', '02', '03', '05', '09', '08', '09']
# ]
```